# ClearCase: How do I know the parent branch of a branch?

Tags: branch, clearcase

Is that possible to get hierarchy of branches?
I have to know the father of a given branch
I have to know the children of a given branch

How do I get it by cleartool?
I prefer not to be based on a view config-spec

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With base ClearCase, you cannot know the parent of a branch, because it can vary from file to file: a file can start branch '`B2`' from '`/main/LATEST`', another can start the same branch from '`/main/B1/LATEST`'.

For ClearCase UCM, you can determine the parent of a branch by querying the ancestors of a Stream (since the branch is name after the stream):

```
cleartool lsstream -anc myStream@pvob
```

That is possible because branches are linked to Streams, which are organized following a strict hierarchy a Parent Stream / Children Streams.

Note that describing a stream (`cleartool describe`, using [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)) only gives you access to the children streams: hence the `lsstream -ancestor`, in order to display its parent.