# Can I add comments in a config_spec file?

Tags: clearcase, config-spec

Does the ClearCase config_spec file syntax support single-line or multi-line comments? If so, how do we mark them?

Answer (score 0):

**Start a line with `#` to make it a comment.**

According to [the config_spec](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm) on the IBM knowledge center,

> Lines that begin with a number sign (#) are comments.

Also remember that empty lines and extra whitespace are ignored, so it's ok to separate comments from commands by empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples of comments (beginning indeed by `#`) in "[Accessing environment variables in Clear Case configuration specification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12209714/6309)"

```
# @(#)$Id:243260.jleffler.toru.cs,v 1.1 2011/08/30 15:23:02 jleffler Exp $
#
# Config Spec for Bug 243260 - Blah, blah, blah, blah

element * CHECKEDOUT
```

There is no multiline comment syntax; like `/* ... */`.